Firebase hosting with vite
I’m working on setting up a GitHub Actions workflow to automatically deploy my Vite application to Firebase Hosting when a pull request (PR) is made and merged. I’ve successfully initialized Firebase Hosting, and everything works fine locally. However, I’m encountering an issue with the GitHub Actions workflow.
when I make a pr.
Could not resolve "./Shell" from "src/components/shell/index.jsx"
my shell comp
export const Shell = React.memo(({ children, data }) => { // Component implementation });
and in the same directory
export { Shell } from './Shell';
Everything works perfectly on my local setup, but the build fails in the GitHub Actions workflow.
I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.
I tried capitalizing the directory or the files because I thought it might be a case sensitivity problem, but I was wrong.
